# How to just save a relationship of a model (worked with transactions before)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am getting further with moving my app to ember-data 1.0 beta, but now I have one particular issue:
We have an `Event` Model, of which multiple get displayed on a particular route and these Events can be liked and commented on (linked with a `hasmany` relationship). In Ember 0.13 the way we saved a comment (similarly like) was the following:

```
saveComment: function(){
    var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
    var  comment = {
      userId: this.get('userId'),
      event: this.get('model'),
      comment: this.get('comment'),
    };
    if (transaction) {
      this.set('transaction', transaction);
      transaction.createRecord(App.Reaction, comment);
    } else {
      console.log('store.transaction() returned null');
    }

    this.get('transaction').commit();
    this.set('comment', '');
}
```

This function lies in the `EventController` and it might have been a little bit of a hack, but it worked beautifully.

I was thinking of creating its own `Controllers` for comments and likes, but would I then be able to easily get the right event id?
Or any other way? Help is as always really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TRANSITION document has a lot of good info about making the switch.

tl,dr; Transactions are gone, so you just create a record and call `.save()` on it.

Something like this:

```
saveComment: function(){
    var  comment = {
      userId: this.get('userId'),
      event: this.get('model'),
      comment: this.get('comment'),
    };

    var reaction = this.store.createRecord('reaction',comment);
    reaction.save();

    this.set('comment', '');
}
```